# bibtex, the last authors Initials are in a different order then the rest of the authors.

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing

When I compile my .bib file using bibtex, the last authors Initials are in a different order then the rest of the authors.  Consider the following example:
the out put should be: 
Xu, L., Jordan, M.I., and Hinton, G.E.

but instead I get the following: 
Xu, L., Jordan, M.I., and G.E, Hinton,

I have included the .bib file and the output.

So the folling code

```
 @article{Übeyli,
  title={An alternative model for mixtures of experts},
  author={Xu, L., Jordan, M.I., and Hinton, G.E.},
  journal={Advances in neural information processing systems},
  pages={633--640},
  year={1995},
  publisher={MORGAN KAUFMANN PUBLISHERS}
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: The problem is that you can't use commas to separate authors in the `.bib` file itself. You need to separate each author with 'and'.

Comment: Thanks Alan Munn.  I though it was an error  in how I created   .bib file

Answer (score 5):

Author names in the `bib` file must be separated by 'and' not commas.  So the correct `bib` file entry should look like this:

```
@article{Übeyli,
  title={An alternative model for mixtures of experts},
  author={Xu, L. and Jordan, M.I. and Hinton, G.E.},
  journal={Advances in neural information processing systems},
  pages={633--640},
  year={1995},
  publisher={Morgan Kaufmann Publishers}
}
```

Also, it's a good idea not to use all caps in any field, but use regular capitalization.

Comment: re your last para: just one of *many* things to fix if you download/cut&paste your bib file - publishers seem to like doing things like that.

Comment: This is interesting; I generally prefer to enter author names as "L. Xu and M.I. Jordan and G.E. Hinton" , as the example given here already puts the authors names into some kind of format. It seems a bit odd, as you first have to deformat and then reformat...

Comment: @AndyClifton The format I suggest allows for names with multiple parts to be parsed correctly by `bibtex` or `biber`. For example, if your have a name *Hans van der Kamp II*, and you enter it as `Hans van der Kamp II` it will come out wrong. If you enter it as `Kamp, Hans van der, II` it will come out correctly.

Comment: Ahhhh. Never seen that one before, but it would explain some oddities. So the logic is {last, first, suffix}?

Comment: @AndyClifton Yes, that's correct.